# Update table after counting matches from another table

Tags: postgresql

I am confused how to write this query

I have 2 tables where the data in table1 needs to be updated based on the results from table2

For instance, if **t1.a** is available in either **t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e** then the result should be 1, but based on the below formula I'm getting sum of the available matches from t2

```
UPDATE public.table1 AS t1 SET result = (select sum(
        CASE WHEN t1.a IN (t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN t1.b IN (t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN t1.c IN (t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN t1.d IN (t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN t1.e IN (t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
 FROM public.table2 AS t2 )
```

Basically my requirement is if the result of t1.a>0 then 1 else 0 + if t1.b>0 then 1 else 0 and so on..

I would prefer to use the query as following where i have added >0 but isn't working;

```
UPDATE public.table1 AS t1 SET result = (select sum(
        CASE WHEN t1.a IN (t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN t1.b IN (t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN t1.c IN (t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN t1.d IN (t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN t1.e IN (t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
 FROM public.table2 AS t2 )
```

Comment: 1) You are using `sum` so why did you expect not  a sum? 2) How about `select case when coalesce(t1.a in (t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e), 'f') THEN 1 else 0 end from public.table2 AS t2`? All you care about is if `t1.a` exists in any of the fields or not.

Comment: 1) Coz i need sum of t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.d and t1.e where the result of each column in t1 should be either 1 or 0

Comment: 1) This, `t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.d and t1.e ` is wrong as those columns are from `t2`. 2) From your problem definition: 'For instance, if t1.a is available in either t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e then the result should be 1', so an `OR` not an `AND`. 3) You need to provide some example data to illustrate what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Add query to question properly formatted as this is unreadable.

Comment: Again, add example data to question that shows the input data and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your problem definition:

```
create table table1 (id integer, a integer, result integer);
create table table2 (id integer, a integer, b integer, c integer, d integer, e integer);
insert into table1 values (1, 3, 0);
insert into table2 values (1, 9,2,5,4,3);
insert into table1 values (1, 8, 0);

select case when coalesce(t1.a in(t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e), 'f') then 1 else 0 end from table1 as t1, table2 t2;
case 
------
    1
    0
update  table1 as t1 set result = (select case when coalesce(t1.a in(t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d, t2.e), 'f') then 1 else 0 end from table2 t2);
select * from table1;
 id | a | result 
----+---+--------
  1 | 3 |      1
  1 | 8 |      0
```

Comment: So does this answer your question?

Comment: Not really, actually there are 5 columns in table1, but in your query only one which is column a only

Comment: and also the following error is occurring; **ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000**

Comment: The provided test case works, so the error means your data is different. A more complete answer awaits you providing the asked for example input data and expected output. Without it any answer is going to be incomplete.